# MinGW64 Rev5 MSYS2 filesystem::copy fails from dir to dir in same drive

Tags: gcc, copy, filesystems

```
#include "main.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;
namespace fs = filesystem;

void testCopy(fs::path from, fs::path to)
{
    try
    {
        fs::copy(from, to,
            fs::copy_options::recursive | fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        wcout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    auto path_drive_d_from = fs::path("D:\\directory have some files");
    auto path_drive_d_to = fs::path("D:\\another empty directory");
    auto path_drive_e_from = fs::path("E:\\dircetory have somem files");
    auto path_drive_e_to = fs::path("E:\\another empty directory");

    testCopy(path_drive_d_from, path_drive_d_to);

// testCopy(path_drive_d_from, path_drive_e_to);

// testCopy(path_drive_e_from, path_drive_e_from);

// testCopy(path_drive_e_from, path_drive_d_to);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested 4 cases and got errors only when copy dir to dir in same drive.
followings are the error message I got.

```
filesystem error: cannot copy: File exists [D:\MyProjects\myProject] [D:\MyProjects\test\unzip]
```

and

```
filesystem error: cannot copy: File exists [E:\test] [E:\test2]
```

Copying dir to dir in other drive was successful. I think this is very weird and can not understand.
I am using c++17 of gcc 11.2.0 of MSYS2.
Please let me know how could I copy a dir to a dir properly. Thank you.
um, each copying test was tried independently, from a dir have files to empty existed dir.

Comment: I could not believe that the elementary code has a bug, I thought some problem with my computer. So I tested the same code on a console project with visual studio, and the code worked perfectly without any problem. Now I guess a problem in 'filesystem' library of g++ of msys2. In Sourceforge's mingw compiler, there was a bug when including 'filesystem', so I used msys2, but another bug occurred. I don't know which g++ compiler to use.

Comment: Finally I give up to resolve this. I use msvc now. It works.